# Pseudoclasse :not() não funciona com combinador

Tags: html, css

Tenho este código `html`:

```
<article>
  <p class="ola"> cafe </p>
  <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
  <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
  <aside>
    <h1>Informações</h1>
    <p>No way</p>
  </aside>
  <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
</article>
```

E este `CSS`:

```
article:not(.ola) p {
background-color: rgb(222, 111, 55);
color: rgb(66, 255, 44);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gioneves/v2hgyoqs/).

Para mim, o parágrafo de classe `ola` deveria ser ignorado, por conta do uso de `:not()` (assim, `cafe` deveria estar sem estilo). Mas, ele também foi estilizado. Não entendo o por que disso. Talvez seja por conta de estar utilizando o **combinador descendente** junto, mas não consegui identificar o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este resultado foi pq vc inverteu a ordem, se quer o **`p`** sem os estilos então é o mesmo que deve receber o **not()**, pode ler mais sobre esta `pseudo-classe` [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:not):

```css
article p:not(.ola) {
  background-color: rgb(222, 111, 55);
  color: rgb(66, 255, 44);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p class="ola"> cafe </p>
  <p>Primeiro parágrafo</p>
  <p>Segundo parágrafo</p>
  <aside>
    <h1>Informações</h1>
    <p>No way</p>
  </aside>
  <p>Terceiro parágrafo</p>
</article>
```